# Force two distance matrices to use and show a common legend

Tags: plotting, matrix, legending, distance

I have two distance matrices. Both are comparing two entities in the same way. I create each matrix using

```
generateDistanceMatrix[centroids_] :=
  Module[{matrix},
   matrix = 
    DistanceMatrix[centroids, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
   Times[matrix, 0.01]];
```

and then I visualize them using

```
visualizeDistanceMatrix[matrix_] :=
  Module[{range},
   range = Range[0, Length[matrix], 20];
   ArrayPlot[matrix,
    Frame -> True,
    ColorFunction -> isoHcf,
    ImageSize -> Full,
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12],
    FrameTicks -> {{range, None}, {None, range}},
    FrameLabel -> {{None, Style["Residue Sequence", 12]},
      {Style["Residue Sequence", 12], None}},
    PlotLegends ->
     {Placed[BarLegend[{isoHcf[#] &, {0, Max[matrix]}},
        LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12],
        LegendLabel -> "Distance (Angstroms)",
        LegendMarkerSize -> 400,
        LegendLayout -> "Column"], {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]];
```

I would like to use `Grid` or something similar to show both distance matrices in the same figure, with a common legend. How can I change this function to force each distance matrix to use a common legend instead of their own?

Comment: Just a side note: Why don't you use just `generateDistanceMatrix[centroids_] :=
  0.01 DistanceMatrix[centroids, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]`?

Comment: That would simplify it, thank you @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: You're welcome. (Btw. `DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance` is the default, so it can also be omitted.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[visualizeDM, barLegend]
isoHcf = ColorData["TemperatureMap"];
visualizeDM[minmax_, is_: 80] := ArrayPlot[#, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[x, isoHcf[Rescale[x, minmax, MinMax@#]]], 
   Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[#, #2 - .5] &, Reverse /@ Transpose[#], {2}], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12], 
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, Style["Residue Sequence", 12]},
     {Style["Residue Sequence", 12], None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 1 -> is] &

barLegend[minmax_] := BarLegend[{isoHcf[Rescale[#, minmax]] &, minmax}, Automatic,  
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], 
  LegendLabel -> "Distance (Angstroms)", LegendMarkerSize -> 400, 
  LegendLayout -> "Column"]
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
centroidlists = RandomReal[100, {2, 5}];
dms = Round[generateDistanceMatrix /@ centroidlists, .01];
dms[[1, 1, 2]] = dms[[1, 2, 1]] = dms[[2, 1, 2]] = dms[[2, 2, 1]] = .55;

minmax = MinMax[dms];

Legended[Row[visualizeDM[minmax] /@ dms, Spacer[5]], Placed[barLegend[minmax], Right]]
```

[image]

**Note:** I added text labels to check that the a given value is mapped to the same color in both plots. Remove the part `Epilog -> ...` to get rid of the labels.

Comment: This works great! I wonder though about the legend. My color function yielded a continuous color scale, whereas this rescaled legend gives discrete colors. Is there a way to rescale continuously? (Let me know if any additional code would be helpful
)

Comment: @briennakh, remove `Automatic` from `BarLegend` to get a continuous gradient.